# Notepad++: Script to send input to running program?

Tags: notepad++, nppexec

I compile and run many .c files in notepad++ using this code

```
NPP_SAVE
g++.exe -g "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" 
a
```

Now what I want is that each time after compilation and running, an input is also sent to the program. Something like below

```
NPP_SAVE
g++.exe -g "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" 
a
28 10 1985 //this is the input to the program a
```

*I have a lot of .c files to check if they give correct output when provided a date.*

Comment: I have similar problem. I would like to redirect input from a file e.g., "input.txt" as the standard input. I tried using "java $(NAME_PART) < input.txt" and it does not work.

Comment: looks like redirection does not work with nppexec as far as I have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to redirect input from file using nppexec is to use cmd

```
cmd /c g++ -o $(NAME_PART).exe $(FILE_NAME) && $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).exe < input.txt
```